# Permission Denied Exception while sharing images from Firefox app to my app

Tags: android, firefox, sharing

As in the title. Sharing images to my app via Intent from Chrome works. It does not work on Firefox though. I am getting following exception:

```
Security Exception: Permission Denial: opening provider mozilla.components.feature.downloads.provider.FileProvider from ProcessRecord{6b46c1f 12229:com.appName/u0a134} (pid=12229, uid=10134) that is not exported from UID 10135
java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: opening provider mozilla.components.feature.downloads.provider.FileProvider from ProcessRecord{6b46c1f 12229:com.appName/u0a134} (pid=12229, uid=10134) that is not exported from UID 10135
```

Answer (score 0):

If you try to share image from Firefox app to any other app than yours It does not work as well. The problem is on the side of Mozilla and can not be easily solved. Even apps like Gmail or SMS(Samsung) don't have this working correctly.

Comment: `you try to share image from Firefox app to any other app than yours` Dont think OP is trying to do that. Moreover it would not matter.

Comment: @blackapps Ever heard of "If there is no solution, the is no problem"? :)